# how do i solve this error " Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"?

Tags: php

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO placed_req(username,goodsauto,minitruck,largetruck,price,qty) VALUES('$user_check','$ga','$mt','$lt','$r','$qty')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$sql2="SELECT reqid FROM placed_req WHERE username='$user_check' AND price='$r'";
$ret=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO inv_detail (inv_id,p_name,qty,price) VALUES('$ret','$user_check','$qty','$r')"; //i'm getting that error in this line
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
if(isset($result1))
    echo "<br></br> Invoice generated successfully";
    header("refresh:10,url=placeorders.php");
} else {
    echo "<br></br> values not selected";
}
```

Comment: why are you including  `sql` stetment in `insert` query

Comment: Can you please print_r($ret); and let me know what is output ?

Comment: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 5 [type] => 0 ) -jalpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want  to put req_id into insert query you must firts fetch req_id correctly

```
$sql2="SELECT reqid FROM placed_req WHERE username='$user_check' AND price='$r'";

$ret=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret);
/* above instruction fetch record from database*/

$inv_id = $row['reqid'];
```

and then put  `$inv_id` into insert query statement

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO inv_detail (inv_id,p_name,qty,price) VALUES('$inv_id','$user_check','$qty','$r')"; //i'm getting that error in this line
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fix your query from

```
"SELECT reqid FROM placed_req WHERE username='$user_check' AND price='$r'";
```

To:

```
"SELECT reqid FROM placed_req WHERE username=\'" . $user_check . "\' AND price=\'" . $r . "\'";
```

And

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO inv_detail (inv_id,p_name,qty,price) VALUES('$ret','$user_check','$qty','$r')";
```

with `$sql1 = "INSERT INTO inv_detail (inv_id,p_name,qty,price) VALUES(\'" . $ret . "\',\'" . $user_check . "\',\'". $qty . "\',\'" . $r . "\')";`

You can finaly use the value of the variables in your query. and like @pritamakumar said, you have to fetch `ret` correctly